How to send a MIME message with the Microsoft Graph SDK for Python
How to send a MIME message with the Microsoft Graph SDK for Python?
There is an example here but that just shows the HTTP request, not how to do it with the SDK.

I think that you need to create RequestInformation for sendMail method and then set stream content of the request body
from typing import Dict
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error import ODataError
from msgraph.generated.users.item.send_mail.send_mail_post_request_body import SendMailPostRequestBody
from kiota_abstractions.serialization import ParsableFactory

async def send_mime_message() :
    graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)
    body = SendMailPostRequestBody()
    request_info = graph_client.me.send_mail.to_post_request_information(body)
    // remove the current Content-Type header which is set to application/json
    request_info.headers.remove(request_info.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER)
    request_info.headers.try_add(request_info.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, "text/plain")
    in_file = open("file_with_mime_content","rb")
    data = in_file.read()
    in_file.close()
    request_info.set_stream_content(data)
    request_adapter = graph_client.request_adapter

    error_mapping: Dict[str, ParsableFactory] = {
            "XXX": ODataError,
        }

    return await request_adapter.send_no_response_content_async(request_info, error_mapping)


This code throws errors.

@Daniel Could you share more details?

None is not a valid parameter to to_post_request_information. Did you try and run the code you posted?

@Daniel Thanks for the feedback. to_post_request_information requires SendMailPostRequestBody(). I've updated the answer
